# 100% Percentage splitted at the number of checked boxes using javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

I have a list of costs for a building (buildings are generated on the fly with PHP from a db):

```
Building
[ ] Susilo 2A-13
[ ] Susilo 2A-12
```

I want it to look like this

```
Building
[ ] Susilo 2A-13 (0%)
[ ] Susilo 2A-12 (0%)
```

when nothing selected, and like this:

```
Building
[x] Susilo 2A-13 (100%)
[ ] Susilo 2A-12 (0%)
```

and also 50% 50% when both selected. Also when 3 buildings showed it should show 33% 33% 33%. How should I do this?

Btw html is simple:

```
Building<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="6" value="6"> Susilo 2A-13<br />
<input type="checkbox" name="7" value="7"> Susilo 2A-12<br />
```

The problem is that those checkboxes are generated on the fly and it's not a constant number.

Comment: Added the html. I taught dividing 100 at the number of checkboxes checked and then showing the result on every innerhtml after those checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have a large number of checkboxes, it may be easiest to do it in Javascript. You tagged this post with JQuery but didn't mention it in your post so I assume you are using it. You could try something like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function markPercentages(){
    var checked = $(':checked');
    var percentage = Math.round((1 / checked.length) * 100);
    checked.siblings('.percentage').html(percentage);
    $('input[type=checkbox]').not(checked).siblings('.percentage').html('0');
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' onclick='markPercentages()'/>Susilo 2A-13 (<span class='percentage'>0</span>%)
</div>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' onclick='markPercentages()' />Susilo 2A-14 (<span class='percentage'>0</span>%)
</div>
<div>
    <input type='checkbox' onclick='markPercentages()' />Susilo 2A-15 (<span class='percentage'>0</span>%)
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll need to make some adjustments to your html to wrap each of those individual percentages in spans as well as the checkbox + text in a div but the concept for calculating it should still be the same.

- Pull out the number of checkboxes
- Take the reciprocal of that number
- Multiply by 100 to get a percentage
- Feed that number back to the form for all the checked items
- Set everything else to 0

Comment: Works like a charm in Chrome but it does not work like suposed in Firefox (it shows 50% on just one checked option where it should show 100%, also 33% on 2 options from 2 checked).

Comment: Interesting. I tried it in FF as well and it worked just fine. Are you running an older version of FF? I'm running 8.0.